# Industry Standard Process for Fraud/Outlier/Anomaly Detection

Tags: anomaly-detection

I want to write my thesis about Fraud Detection in ERP Databases. I'm looking for a Industry Standard Processs such as CRISP-DM for Data Mining Projects, in order to justify my approach in solving the issue of finding outliers/anomalies in the data set.
Is there any established Standard Process which would be more suitable for such an project?

Thanks.

Comment: what industry are you in? I imagine if standards exist, then they likely differ by subdomain, e.g., credit card fraud vs. insurance fraud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [great book on Fraud Analytics](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Fraud+Analytics+Using+Descriptive%2C+Predictive%2C+and+Social+Network+Techniques%3A+A+Guide+to+Data+Science+for+Fraud+Detection-p-9781119133124). It's quite comprehensive and has a detailed list of original research references and other textbooks at the end of each chapter.

[Fraud Analytics Using Descriptive, Predictive, and Social Network Techniques: A Guide to Data Science for Fraud Detection
Bart Baesens, Veronique Van Vlasselaer, Wouter Verbeke
ISBN: 978-1-119-13312-4
Aug 2015](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Fraud+Analytics+Using+Descriptive%2C+Predictive%2C+and+Social+Network+Techniques%3A+A+Guide+to+Data+Science+for+Fraud+Detection-p-9781119133124)

Answer (score 3):

You should refer [this survey paper](http://cucis.ece.northwestern.edu/projects/DMS/publications/AnomalyDetection.pdf) on Anomaly Detection (from University of Minnesota).

Please let me know if this helps you.

Comment: The paper appears to be very encouraging. I'll get in touch later on as the paper is very comprehensive.